# Parent node should be closed when child node is open

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, jstree

This is the result:

[image: image1]

This is what the page shows when the JSON sets `childnode.state.selected` 
For example:

```
{"children":[],"id":37,"text":"应用显 示","orderid":1,"parent":36,"state":{"disabled":false,"opened":false,"selected":true},"type":2,"url":"application\\list.action"}
```

When this happens, the parent node will open. I want it closed.

When `selected_parent_open` is set false it should solve the problem, but I set it and it still doesn't work.

```
var control = $('#' + treeName)
control.data('jstree', false);//清空数据，必须
                              // empty data
var isCheck = arguments[2] || false; //设置checkbox默认值为false
                                     // set default checkbox value to false 
if(isCheck) {
    //复选框树的初始化
    // initialize checkbox tree
    $.getJSON(url,jsondata, function (data) {
        control.jstree({
            "ui":{selected_parent_open:false},
            'plugins' : [ "checkbox" ], //出现选择框
                                        // selection box
            'checkbox': { cascade: "", three_state: true }, //不级联
                                                            // don't cascade
            'core': {
                'data': data,
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                }
            }
        }).on('loaded.jstree',loadedfunction);
    });
}
```

What should I do?

What I need is:

[image: image2]

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's a valid question (albeit with some Chinese and bad grammar). If you don't like it, edit it!

Comment: thank for you edit,waitting for answer,my english will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem at all. It just works without any extra configuration.
Can you check this demo: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/nLpw30ap/)

```
$('#tree')
  .jstree({
    "core" : {
      "data" : data,
      "themes": {
          "url": true,
          "icons": true
      }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ],
    "checkbox": { three_state: true }
 });
```